# how Nginx block empty user agent if not from specific ips

Tags: nginx, user-agent, plesk

I'm trying to block with Nginx any request coming from empty user agent if not originated from specific IPs.

Since Nginx doesn't allow nested ifs, I tried:

```
set $precond 0;
if ( $remote_addr != XX.XX.XX.XX|YY.YY.YY.YY ){set $precond precond+1;}
if ($http_user_agent ~* "-") {set $precond precond+1;}
if ($precond = 2){return 403;}
```

I placed it at "Additional nginx directives" of the page "Apache & nginx Settings" at Plesk Control Panel.

I couldn't have the wanted result.

Can you help please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

nginx does not have any arithmetic operations, only string concatenation. This better be done with nginx `map` block substitutions, but since you don't have access to the full nginx config, try this:

```
set $deny '1';
if ($http_user_agent) { set $deny ''; }
if ($remote_addr = X.X.X.X) { set $deny ''; }
if ($remote_addr = Y.Y.Y.Y) { set $deny ''; }
if ($remote_addr = Z.Z.Z.Z) { set $deny ''; }
if ($deny) { return 403; }
```

or using regex matching of remote IP address:

```
set $deny '1';
if ($http_user_agent) { set $deny ''; }
if ($remote_addr ~ ^(X\.X\.X\.X|Y\.Y\.Y\.Y|Z\.Z\.Z\.Z)$) { set $deny ''; }
if ($deny) { return 403; }
```

Note that the dot symbol should be prefixed with slash in regex expressions or it would have meaning of any symbol.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your answer, I need the 2 conditions to be fulfilled to return 403. At the same received request if http_user_agent = "-" and remote_addr is different than those specified  I should return 403.

Comment: @ZainabBEGDOURI As I understand, you need to process the request if `User-Agent` HTTP header is present **OR** if the request originated from some specific IP? This configuration should do exactly that. It seems you even didn't checked if it works, did you?

Comment: I should accept request with empty user agent only if the remote_addr is one of specified ips

Comment: I should not deny all requests with empty http_user_agent. I should not deny all requests different than my specified ips.

Comment: **Aaarghhh** When we had two conditions -  user-agent is empty (lets say condition A) and source IP not from our list (condition B), we can say we should block request when A is true **and** B is true, or we can say that we should pass request when A is false **or** B is false. `NOT (A AND B) == (NOT A) OR (NOT B)`, it is a boolean arithmetic. This config should do exactly what you want, please stop explaining me, I got it first time. Check this config in production even if you couldn't understand how it works.